# Can I automatically generate a Table of Contents (.hhc) using hhc.exe or other commandline tool?

Tags: chm

The HTML Help Workshop gui (hhw.exe) has an option 'Automatically create contents file (.hhc) when compiling'.  Is there a way to get the same behavior from a commandline tool (e.g., hhc.exe)?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik the cmdline tool still uses the .hhp?

From

http://www.nongnu.org/chmspec/latest/INI.html#HHP

put in your .hhp:

**Auto TOC= number**    This uses the heading tags in your HTML files to generate the contents. The number is the maximum level of tag to place in the contents. eg 1 = , 2 = , 9 =  WARNING: HHW modifies your HHC file if you specify this. IMO this is a bug: HHW should just slurp through a pipe or temporary file.